# Convert NSString in to Cocos2d-x CCString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, cocos2d-x

i need to convert `NSString` in to`CCString` .

i have NSString value form gamecenter player name . now i need to convert that in to ccstring for display in cocos2dx game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:-

```
NSString *gamecentername = @"Hello"; 
CCString *playernamename =  (CCString*)[gamecentername UTF8String];
```